# Who vrs whom: is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

“ Dave is his best friend who he has known for years”

I was told I have to use “whom” here, but can it also be “who” in any way?

Comment: **Strictly speaking**, 'whom' is correct, but, as many people will tell you, 'who' is very commonly used today.

Comment: People who use _whom_, when speaking in a register in which they use _whom_, will use _whom_ in this sentence. Many people do not use _whom_, and even those who do so don't necessarily use it in informal speech.

Comment: **Strictly speaking**, *who* is correct in modern English, but *whom* is also still commonly used.